# How does fprintf work in C++?

Tags: c++, printf, internals

How does fprintf work?

If I write `fprintf(outfile, "test %d %d 255/r", 255, 255);`

What does it mean?
I know that outfile is the name my of output file. 
What would the other values mean?

Comment: You should also question your knowledge of the first parameter. "outfile" in **not** the *name* of your output file.

Comment: It's kinda sad, the first result of a "fprintf" google search would have told you everything about it.

Comment: True, but now *this* discussion has a chance to show up in Google for the next person. Take that frown and turn it upside down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"test %d %d 255/r"` tells that after it will be arguments (and they are there: 255, 255) and they are expected to be of integer type. And they will be placed instead of %d.

In result you'll get string `test 255 255 255` in your file.

For more infrormation read [`std::fprintf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter is a file handle, the second is a formatting string, and after that there is a variable number of arguments depending on how many format specifiers you used in your 2nd parameter.

Check the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), it contains all of the information you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

it's a formatted output to a file stream. It works like printf does, the difference is that printf always outputs to stdout.If you wrote

```
fprintf(stdout, "test %d %d 255\n", 255, 255);
```

it would be the same as the `printf` equivalent.

The second argument to it is the format string. The format string contains format specifiers, like `%s`, `%d`, `%x`. Yours contains two `%d`s. Each format specifier must have a corresponding argument in `fprintf`. Yours has two `%d` specifiers, so there are two numerical arguments:

```
fprintf(outfile, "Here are two numbers: %d, %d", 4, 5);
```

likewise, you could use string specifiers (`%s`), hexadecimal specifiers (`%x`) or long/long long int specifiers (`%ld`, `%lld`). Here is a list of them: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/printf. Note that they are the same for all of the C formatted i/o functions (like sprintf and scanf).

Also, in your original example, "`/r`" will just literally print "`/r`". It looks like you were trying to do a carriage return ("`\r`").

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to [printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf), it just prints the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is the format string.  Any additional arguments are the parameters to the specifier in the format string (in this case, %d).  Check out http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/printf for a good intro to printf-style functions.